# The probability a survey participant is watching a certain channel(s)

Tags: probability

There are 3 TV channels: A, B, C. From a survey conducted among viewers the following probabilities were found:

1. $$P(watch\space no\space channel) = P(A^c\cap B^c \cap C^c) = 0.3$$
2. $$P(watch\space exactly\space 2\space channels) = P(A\cap B \cap C^c)+P(A\cap B^c \cap C) + P(A^c\cap B\cap C) = 0.25$$
3. $$P(watch\space exactly\space 1\space channel) = P(A\cap B^c \cap C^c)+P(A^c\cap B \cap C^c) + P(A^c\cap B^c\cap C) = 0.37$$
4. $$P(A\cup B) = 0.56$$
5. $$P(A\cap B|A\cup B) = 0.25$$
6. $$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C|B\cup C) = \frac{2}{9}$$

I need to fill up the corresponding Venn diagram.
so from item (1) I got that

7. $$P(A\cup B \cup C) = 1 - P(A^c\cap B^c \cap C^c) = 0.7$$

then from (4) I got

8. $$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C) = P(A\cup B \cup C) - P(A\cup B) = 0.7 -
       0.56 = 0.14$$

and from (6) I get

9. $$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C|B\cup C) = \frac{P((A^c \cap B^c \cap C)
       \cap (B\cup C))}{P(B\cup C)} = \frac{P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C)}{P(B\cup
       C)}=\frac{2}{9}\Longrightarrow P(B\cup C) = (9 \cdot 0.14) / 2 =
       0.63$$
10. $$\Longrightarrow P(A\cap B^c \cap C^c) = P(A\cup B \cup C) - P(B\cup C) = 0.7 -
        0.63 = 0.07$$

and from (3), (8) and (10) I get

11. $$P(A^c\cap B \cap C^c) = 0.16$$

from (2), (3) and (7) I get

12. $$P(A\cap B \cap C) = 0.7 - 0.37 - 0.25 = 0.08$$

from (4) and (5) I get

13. $$P(A\cap B|A\cup B) = \frac{P((A\cap B)\cap (A\cup B)}{P(A\cup B)} = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A\cup B)} = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{0.56} = 0.25 \Longrightarrow P(A\cap B) = 0.14$$

and from (12) and (13) I get

14. $$P(A\cap B \cap C^c) = P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap B \cap C) = 0.14 - 0.08 = 0.06$$

I still need to calculate $P(A\cap B^c \cap C)$ and $P(A^c\cap B \cap C)$ but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding Venn diagram has eight elementary domains, but in the problem are provided only six equalities. Together with condition that the sum of all probabilities is one, we have seven equalities, that is an underdetermined system.

We show that the problem has no unique solution by considering the set $V$ of elementary domains (named like $A^*\cap B^*\cap C^*$) as a set of elementary events of a probability space with the probabilities taken from your solution and satisfying all problem conditions. Namely, we put

$P(A\cap B \cap C)=0.08,$

$P(A\cap B \cap C^c)=0.06,$

$P(A\cap B^c \cap C)=x,$

$P(A\cap B^c \cap C^c)=0.07,$

$P(A^c\cap B \cap C)=0.19-x,$

$P(A^c\cap B \cap C^c)=0.16,$

$P(A^c\cap B^c \cap C)=0.14,$

$P(A^c\cap B^c \cap C^c)=0.3.$

It is easy to check that for any $0\le x\le 0.19$ all problem conditions are satisfied.